# Project building using maven

Tags: maven, project

I am building my project using maven I am getting following error ...can any one tell why it is happening? My internet connection is ok is there any proxy setting problem?

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ftp/1.0-beta-6/wagon-ftp-1.0-beta-6.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ftp:pom:1.0-beta-6' from repository central Error transferring file: Connection timed out

Comment: That sounds like a network problem, cause i can download that file without any problem.

Comment: no my network connection is ok..

Answer (score 0):

You can find the following proxy setting template in the Maven configuration file , which is located at `MAVEN_HOME_DIR\conf\settings.xml`

```
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
  </proxies>
```

Did you configure the proxy setting  ?

---

**Reference**

[Maven - Guide to using proxies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

Comment: yes I did 
       <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>192.168.0.233</host>
            <port>3128</port>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>